# In a software architecture, when do I use Service Fabric vs Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to understand the MSFT form of Microservices (Docker) called Service Fabric and am confused about when to use Service Fabric or [Function apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs)

What guidance should I follow when choosing?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/maheshkshirsagar/2016/11/21/choosing-between-azure-container-service-azure-service-fabric-and-azure-functions/

Comment: Additional hints to consider: https://medium.com/@WorkloadRancher/service-fabric-functions-and-app-services-which-ones-for-me-4e275128ed0